# How to enable the rendering of Reference Images on Blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, image

I placed reference images to decorate some objects but they don't show up on the final rendering. Is it possible to enable their rendering? Or if not, can I transform them in an object that can be rendered?

Comment: NEVERMIND IDK HOW TO DELETE THIS

Comment: I ALREADY KNOW ITS NOT POSSIBLE I HAVE TO CREATE AN IMAGE AS PLANE FOR EXAMPLE